# URL.createObjectURL,method doesn't work for PDF or .doc files in LWC components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, experience-cloud, community-cloud

I am trying to create a URL from the blob of an inputted PDF file from the browser (Chrome).  The below snippet doesn't work when receiving PDF files as input but DOES work with pngs and jpegs. I'm not receiving an error or anything helpful. The readFile method returns unexpectedly whenever the URL.createObjectURL method on the second line is invoked on a pdf. What am I doing wrong?

```
readFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const blob = URL.createObjectURL(file); // the code seems to fail here without error
}
```

Comment: I believe this question would be better addressed on a different site since it is about browser technology rather than Salesforce.

Comment: @PhilW This is about LWC, which is firmly in our scope. When something works not-in-Salesforce, but doesn't work in Salesforce, it's almost certainly a Locker Service or Lightning Web Security issue, which sites like [so] might not be able to address correctly.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works outside the LWC context?

Comment: @PhilW [Demo working in LWR](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/mapRvrliCjNyAQuKXP8n/src/app.html?p=stories)

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. Should it?

Comment: @sfdcfox Hey thanks for your reply. I ran into the same approach you did with this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_mime. I got a bit overzealous and "answered" my question before I read your comment.

Comment: @SalCarrera No worries! Glad you found the answer.

Comment: @PhilW Apparently you were technically correct (the best kind). Still, I don't necessarily think it needs to be moved to [so], because we do support JS within the context of LWC. Also, the demo just adds a download link (manually click it to download); I tested it in Chrome, but not others, so might be some kind of discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work after reading this. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_mime

I changed my code from

```
readFile(file) {
 const reader = new FileReader();
 const blob = URL.createObjectURL(file); // the code seems to fail here without error 
}
```

to

```
readFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const blob = new Blob([file], {type: file?.type}); // works as expected

}
```